# How to add JVM options to program started by mvn spring-boot:run

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

What is the best way to add JVM options to the program started by `mvn spring-boot:run`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can configure `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to always include you jvm options when run:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <jvmArguments>
            -Dapp.name=test
        </jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Or if you don't need that arguments to stay permanently, use this on the command line:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="..."
```

Check [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) for details.

Answer (score 11):

Now it is:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
```