# Spring Boot read environment variables inside application-properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I have been trying to figure out how to use environment-variables in either application.properties or application.yaml. Since this works in countless frameworks (such as Laravel for example), I assumed this would also work in Spring Boot. Now as I have found out, this is not the case.

I saw a post about Spring Environment API, that started that the environment-variable SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL would be equivalent to setting spring.datasource.url inside my application. However, this also didn't work for me.

Is there any quick way that allows using variables that are declared inside a .env file?

I'd like to use it like this inside the application.properties if possible.
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}`

Comment: It works for environment or any other variables **but** there is no support for .env files as those aren't exposed as environment variables afaik.

Comment: Do you have an alternative solution for this? For example, I want to run it locally by running with configuration file, but when using it with docker, I want to set the properties via. OS Environment variables.

Comment: you can have multiple profiles, set variable values as different for each profile and load them during startup

Comment: Exposing regular environemt variables works out-of-the-box. It is only that .env file that isn't supported. A docker environment variable just works.

Comment: So if I want it to work with a pure application.properties file in dev and env-variables in prod, I can just create a appilaction-dev.properties with absolute values and a application-prod.properties that uses the ${VAR_NAME} syntax?

Comment: Or don't. Why not simply pass `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` as an environment property instead of 3 separate ones and try to shoehorn those back into `spring.datasource.url` (etc.). If you have an `application.properties` with `spring.datasource.url` and pass an `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` as environment variable the latter takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

.env is way of Python. If you use spring cloud, you can read env variable from configServer then inject them into application.properties.

1. add some dependency into pom.xml

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

2. define a yml to locate config-server. for example, called myBootstrap.yml

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      fail-fast: true
      uri: http://[config-server-git]
      name: cc
      profile: config
      label: maste
```

3. define a file named cc-config.properties and push it into config-server git. The env variables are written in this properties.
4. use below way to run application jar

```sh
java -jar [your-application-jar] --spring.cloud.bootstrap.location=myBootstrap.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I start Java Spring Boot applications from within nvim on an Ubuntu Linux machine in a terminal is by using the trick [Dat Tran](https://datmt.com/backend/java/run-mvn-spring-bootrun-with-environment-variables/) posted recently:

```bash
set -a; . /path/to/.env; set +a; mvn spring-boot:run
```

`set -a;` and `set +a` are thereby built-in shell/bash commands where the `-a` option is documented as:

> Each variable or function that is created or modified is given the export attribute and marked for export to the environment of subsequent commands.

where the `+a` option [basically unsets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372774/set-a-does-not-unset-the-a-flag) the `-a` option and allowing stuff that comes afterwards to access the environment variables created during the `-a` case. This allows Spring Boot basically to pick up environment variables and replace their placeholders in `application.yaml` or `application.properties` files.

If you want to pass additional configuration parameters like adding a debugger or opening certain modules you need to also append the following configuration, as explained i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735189/how-to-add-jvm-options-to-program-started-by-mvn-spring-bootrun), to the command string from above:

```bash
... -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="--add-opens java.base/java.utils=ALL-UNNAMED -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

This will instruct Maven to pass along the configuration options to the Spring app.